# Mobilefirst 7.1 Push notification - Send Message REST API vs submitNotification(userId, notificationText)

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

Our requirement is to send unicast push notifications. For which we have created an Event source and subscribed user as mentioned in this [documentation](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/6.3/notifications/push-notifications-hybrid-applications/)

But which method is correct to send push notification? What are Pros and Cons of using one or the other

```
submitNotification(userId, notificationText)
```

1)Should we use the method we declared in Push Adapter.

2)The [Send Message (POST)](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/r_restapi_send_message_post.html?lang=en) from [REST API Runtime Services](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.apiref.doc/rest_runtime/c_restapi_runtime.html?lang=en). Is this the correct way to send Unicast notifications.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods are valid ones.

You would use the REST option if you'd like to "automate" the sending of the notifications. Some prefer using REST endpoints, some prefer using an adapter - you use the approach that suits you best.

Comment: Thanks Idan Adar! What do you mean by the "automate"? Are you talking about the Send Bulk message?

Comment: Also help me to know does Send Bulk message has some messaging queue implemented?

Comment: Use your adapter if you want your adapter to be the one sending the messages, use the REST API if you want some external server to send the messages.  I do not know the internal implementation of "bulk" API, but it is meant to be for sending multiple messages at once.