# MFP 7.1 - SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

We see this error a lot on our Test server. This happens usually after application has been into background for a while. Once this error occurs user is not able to do any thing. This issue goes off once App is killed and restarted.

```
[4/24/16 19:08:23:195 EDT] 0000927c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension                            W SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
[4/24/16 19:08:23:195 EDT] 0000927c com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter            E FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4867)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1017)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1766)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
 [project MyProject]
java.io.FileNotFoundException: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.extension.DefaultExtensionProcessor.handleRequest(DefaultExtensionProcessor.java:528)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.invokeTarget(WebAppFilterChain.java:150)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:93)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter$1.execute(AuthenticationFilter.java:224)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationServiceBean.accessResource(AuthenticationServiceBean.java:82)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:229)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4867)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1017)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1766)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)

[4/24/16 19:08:23:197 EDT] 0000927c com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp                               E SRVE0293E: [Servlet Error]-[FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url [project MyProject]]: com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppErrorReport: FWLSE0304E: Unhandled exception caught: SRVE0190E: File not found: /apps/services/my_custom_auth_request_url [project MyProject]
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:629)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppDispatcherContext.sendError(WebAppDispatcherContext.java:647)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.srt.SRTServletResponse.sendError(SRTServletResponse.java:1303)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:289)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:207)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:90)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:1020)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1142)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4867)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:997)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink.ready(HttpDispatcherLink.java:341)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:470)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.handleNewRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:404)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.processRequest(HttpInboundLink.java:284)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.internal.inbound.HttpInboundLink.ready(HttpInboundLink.java:255)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink.determineNextChannel(SSLConnectionLink.java:1017)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLConnectionLink$MyReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLConnectionLink.java:626)
    at com.ibm.ws.channel.ssl.internal.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1766)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.requestComplete(WorkQueueManager.java:504)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.attemptIO(WorkQueueManager.java:574)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager.workerRun(WorkQueueManager.java:929)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcpchannel.internal.WorkQueueManager$Worker.run(WorkQueueManager.java:1018)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
```

Comment: Are you using a custom authenticator and login module? Does this maybe happen when you put the app in the background while in the middle of the authentication flow?

Comment: Thats correct I am using Custom Authenticator and Login Module

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you are using a custom authenticator, and that your challenge handler uses `submitLoginForm` with the url `my_custom_auth_request_url`.

First, make sure that of course your custom authenticator knows how to respond to `my_custom_auth_request_url`.

But most likely, the error you are seeing is because you are trying to do a `submitLoginForm` outside of a challenge context.

Meaning, either:

- you are trying to login before receiving any challenge.
- you received a challenge, let the session expire, and then try to answer it too late.
- You did not make sure that every single challenge you receive either ends by a `submitLoginForm` or a `submitFailure`.
- It could also be related to your other question ([MFP 7.1 - FWLSE0342E: Grant code validation failed: Grant code was already used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825428/mfp-7-1-fwlse0342e-grant-code-validation-failed-grant-code-was-already-used)). If your sessions are not handled correctly, you lose the context of the challenge.